# how to use the second row in a wide data format as an extra variable name

Tags: r, rows

I have a data frame where the first row is the col names (of course), but the second row is an extra information and a variable I want to apply statistics on it/ For example, the first row is the ID of a plant, the second row is the location and the rest of the rows are the dependent variables on a time series. It is important to note that the first col is my x- axis and it represents the time. Here is a pieces of my data:

```
Days L-FCS L-DRC    L-PCH   S-PCH   S-PCH   S-SSV   M-SSV   L-SSV   S-DRC   L-MNS   L-DRC
Room  1-BR-SW 1-BR-SW   1-BR-SW 1-BR-SW 1-BR-SW 1-BR-SW 1-BR-SW 2-BR-SE 2-BR-SE 2-BR-SE 
0.00    0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
0.04    0   0   1   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   0
0.08    0   0   1   0   0   1   2   0   0   0   0
0.13    0   0   -1  0   0   2   3   0   0   0   0
0.17    0   0   -1  0   0   3   4   0   0   0   0
0.21    0   0   -1  0   0   4   5   0   0   0   0
0.25    0   0   -1  0   0   4   6   0   0   0   0
0.29    0   0   -2  0   0   4   6   0   0   0   0
0.33    0   0   -1  0   0   4   6   0   0   0   0
0.38    -1  0   -1  0   0   4   6   0   0   0   0
0.42    -2  0   -1  0   0   4   6   0   0   0   0
0.46    -5  0   -1  0   0   4   6   0   0   0   0
0.50    -5  0   -2  0   0   4   6   0   0   -1  0
0.54    -5  0   -2  0   0   4   6   0   0   -2  0
0.58    -6  0   -3  0   0   4   7   0   0   -3  0
0.63    -8  0   -3  0   0   4   8   0   0   -3  0
0.67    -9  0   -3  0   0   4   8   0   0   -3  0
0.71    -9  0   -3  0   0   4   11  0   -1  -3  0
0.75    -9  0   -3  0   0   4   11  0   -1  -4  0
0.79    -9  0   -3  0   0   4   13  0   -1  -5  0
0.83    -10 0   -3  0   0   4   13  0   -1  -5  0
0.88    -12 0   -3  0   0   4   13  0   -1  -5  0
0.92    -13 0   -4  0   0   4   13  0   -1  -6  0
0.96    -14 0   -5  0   -1  4   13  0   -1  -6  0
1.00    -14 0   -5  0   -1  4   13  0   -1  -6  0
1.04    -15 0   -5  0   -1  4   13  0   -2  -6  0
1.08    -16 0   -5  0   -1  4   13  0   -2  -6  0
```

I omitted some of the rows names because it does not fit here with the col ( 1st and 2nd row names are too wide for the numbers)

Af for future use, I'd love to know how can I use any multiple rows as variables for my data. I tried to reshape it into a long format ( and I use long format with this data for other purposes) yet I could not find how to reshape it so I have those columns as well.

What I did so far is to omit the second row entirely so I had only the Days col and it's first call is the 0.00

Attached with dput() again:

```
structure(list(Days = c("Room", "0.00", "0.04", "0.08", "0.13", 
"0.17"), L.FCS = c("1-BR-SW", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), L.DRC = c("1-BR-SW", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), L.PCH = c("1-BR-SW", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0"), S.PCH = c("1-BR-SW", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), S.PCH.1 = c("1-BR-SW", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0"), S.SSV = c("1-BR-SW", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0"), Hodaya_M = c("1-BR-SW", "0", "1", "1", "3", "3"), 
    L.SSV = c("2-BR-SE", "0", "-1", "-1", "-2", "-2"), S.DRC = c("2-BR-SE", 
    "0", "0", "-1", "-1", "-1")), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: It seems that `L-DRC` column appears twice. Does other columns appears multiple times too?

Comment: Can you please share this in the form of code so that we can load it directly? This can be done from R by running `dput(YOUR_TABLE_NAME)` and pasting the result into the text of your question.

Comment: Yes, I have the same names of plants a few times, but they are coded with numbers as well that have been omitted here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest extracting the header info and the data separately, and then combining the two.

```
library(tidyverse)
df1_headers <- df1 %>%
  janitor::clean_names() %>%   # Reformats names and makes them unique
  slice(1) %>%   # only keep the first data row, your "location"
  mutate(across(,as.character)) %>%  # make everything character data
  pivot_longer(everything(), values_to = "location")

df1_body <- df1 %>% 
  janitor::clean_names() %>%
  slice(-1) %>%   # remove only the first row
  mutate(across(,as.numeric),       # make numeric
         row = row_number()) %>%    # add row number in case days not unique / ordered
  pivot_longer(-c(row, days))

df_long <- df1_body %>% left_join(df1_headers)
```

This format should be pretty flexible for further analysis and visualization, e.g.

```
ggplot(df_long, aes(days, value, color = name)) +
  geom_line() +
  facet_wrap(~location)
```

[image]

Source data

```
df1 <- data.frame(
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE,
       check.names = FALSE,
              Days = c("Room","0","0.04","0.08",
                       "0.13","0.17","0.21","0.25","0.29","0.33","0.38",
                       "0.42","0.46","0.5","0.54","0.58","0.63","0.67",
                       "0.71","0.75","0.79","0.83","0.88","0.92","0.96","1",
                       "1.04","1.08"),
           `L-FCS` = c("1-BR-SW","0","0","0","0",
                       "0","0","0","0","0","-1","-2","-5","-5","-5",
                       "-6","-8","-9","-9","-9","-9","-10","-12","-13",
                       "-14","-14","-15","-16"),
           `L-DRC` = c("1-BR-SW","0","0","0","0",
                       "0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0",
                       "0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"),
           `L-PCH` = c("1-BR-SW","0","1","1","-1",
                       "-1","-1","-1","-2","-1","-1","-1","-1","-2",
                       "-2","-3","-3","-3","-3","-3","-3","-3","-3","-4",
                       "-5","-5","-5","-5"),
           `S-PCH` = c("1-BR-SW","0","0","0","0",
                       "0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0",
                       "0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"),
           `S-PCH` = c("1-BR-SW","0","0","0","0",
                       "0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0",
                       "0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","-1","-1","-1",
                       "-1"),
           `S-SSV` = c("1-BR-SW","0","0","1","2",
                       "3","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4",
                       "4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4","4"),
           `M-SSV` = c("1-BR-SW","0","1","2","3",
                       "4","5","6","6","6","6","6","6","6","6","7",
                       "8","8","11","11","13","13","13","13","13","13",
                       "13","13"),
           `L-SSV` = c("2-BR-SE","0","0","0","0",
                       "0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0",
                       "0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"),
           `S-DRC` = c("2-BR-SE","0","0","0","0",
                       "0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0",
                       "0","0","-1","-1","-1","-1","-1","-1","-1","-1",
                       "-2","-2"),
           `L-MNS` = c("2-BR-SE","0","0","0","0",
                       "0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","-1","-2","-3",
                       "-3","-3","-3","-4","-5","-5","-5","-6","-6",
                       "-6","-6","-6"),
           `L-DRC` = c(NA,0L,0L,0L,0L,0L,0L,0L,
                       0L,0L,0L,0L,0L,0L,0L,0L,0L,0L,0L,0L,0L,0L,
                       0L,0L,0L,0L,0L,0L)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Worked perfectly. Just to make sure, which line of code is that I need to apply/change for future use with even more than two rows? i.e. I have the plant name, the location and the pot type

Comment: `slice(1)` would become `slice(1:2)` and `slice(-1)` would become `slice(-(1:2))`

Answer (score 0):

Two options to solve this problem come to mind: First, what you have in the first row of the dataframe are labels. So, one can treat this information as labels. Second, and this is the less elegant solution, pasting together the column names and text labels from the first row. I present both options below:

```
library(tidyverse)

# this is an example dataframe (easier version of what you posted)
df <- tibble(
  time = c('text1', 1:4),
  var1 = c('text2', 2:5),
  var2 = c('text3', 3:6)
)
df

#######################
# OPTION 1: Labelling #
#######################

# load package for lable function
library(Hmisc)

# set first row as label
label(df) <- df[1,]

# remove first row with label information (since now set as label)
df <- df[-1,]

print(df)
label(df)

######################################################
# OPTION 2: Pasting together column names and labels #
######################################################

# get text from column names + first row
text1 <- names(df)
text2 <- as.character(df[1,])

# paste together both strings
new_col_header <- paste(text1, text2, sep = "__")

# remove first row with label information
df <- df[-1,]

# rename columns with new info
colnames(df) <- new_col_header

print(df)
```